# Initialize std::chrono::time_point variable with zero

Tags: c++, std

I have a variable called last_timestamp_  which is declared as follows:

`using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<double>> TimePoint last_timestamp_`

and I want to initialize it with zero, how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: It defaults to 0 so, `TimePoint time = {}`.

Comment: What sholud a "zero time point" mean? Do you mean its time since epoch is 0?

Comment: I want a way to say if enough time passed since  last_timestamp_ so I am doing the following: if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() > last_timestamp_ + threshold) then...

Comment: @erez This does not imply you need to set `last_timestamp_` to "zero" (whatever it should mean). What is wrong about setting it to `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` instead? Basically, you need a duration between two time points and compare it with your threshold.

Comment: The condition may be false in the first time if last_timestamp_ is set to now... I need a way to make it true for the first time.

Comment: This seems to be an _X-Y problem_. I would recommend to edit the question and describe the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Initialize it to `std::chrono::system_clock::now() - threshold`. That way, it is always at least `threshold` units old.

Answer (score 2):

```
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, 
    std::chrono::duration<double>>;
TimePoint last_timestamp_{};
```

It would actually work without the `{}` too, but imho it is better style to explicitly zero-initialize it.

You can read this two ways:

1. It internally sets the value of `last_timestamp_` to `0.0s`, or to its epoch.
2. It sets `last_timestamp_` to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

The reason you can say the second part is because it is a de-facto standard that all implementations track [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with `system_clock` in C++11/14/17.  For C++20 this industry practice has been [officially specified](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1).

*Important note:*  This specification is strictly for `time_point`s based on `system_clock`.  One can not assume this epoch for all chrono `time_point`s.

Presuming from the comments that your use looks like:

```
while (...)
{
    if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() > last_timestamp_ + threshold)
    {
        // now() - last_timestamp_ > threshold
        ...
        last_timestamp_ = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }
};
```

Your first iteration will be true assuming `threshold` isn't larger than 51 years.

Just to future-proof your code, it's worth a comment:

```
TimePoint last_timestamp_{};  // 1970-01-01
```

Now if you change clocks for any reason, you know that you may have to revisit this initial value.  For example on some platforms the epoch of `file_clock` will be far in the future, breaking this code if it switched to `file_clock`.  C++20 offers syntax to make this initialization more explicit:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
TimePoint last_timestamp_ = std::chrono::sys_days{1970y/1/1};
```

Now the comment is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The method std::chrono::time_point::min() represents the minimum possible value, which is the "zero" you are looking for.

```
using MyTimeType = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
MyTimeType my_time = MyTimeType::min();
```

Comment: Did you try compiling your answer?

Comment: Thank you Howard, I had a mistake, fixing my comment, please check it again